# Internet Permission issue in Android App?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-internet

App name is: ThreadingNoThreading

Faulty Class Name: threading.java

Mine is a simple program. This particular class has two Buttons. One to toast and another to download the image from internet and set it in the image view. Using AsyncTask for the Threading.

When I run the program on my MOTO E, it throws a Runtime exception, stating that it requires INTERNET permission, which I have already provided. It seems that I am missing a part of puzzle to run this app successfully.

NOTE: Debugging this app via my laptop which is connected to WIFI, so I have disabled my LAN Card on Laptop. (As I read, the Android system looks into the LAN CARD as the primary connection)

Please help me to understand, if I am missing anything.

Below is my class:
**Threading.java**

```
package android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Sony on 18-08-2015.
 */
public class Threading extends Activity {

    Button threadingToastButton, threadingImageViewButton;
    ImageView threadingImageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_for_threading);

        threadingImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.threadingImageView);
        threadingImageViewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.threadingImageViewButton);
        threadingToastButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.threadingToastButton);

        // Start the Async Task to download the image, when this button is pressed.
        threadingImageViewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DownloadImage().execute("http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120826123355/vssaxtonhale/images/c/c2/Troll-face.png");
            }
        });


        threadingToastButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });



    }


    // Set a drawable to the image view
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void setImage(Drawable drawable) {
        threadingImageView.setBackground(drawable);
    }


    // Inner class to download the image
    public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Drawable> {

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return downloadImage(strings[0]);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {
            setImage(drawable);
        }

        // Logic to download the image
        private Drawable downloadImage(String _url) {

            // Prepare to download the imate
            URL url;
            InputStream inputStream;
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;

            try {
                url = new URL(_url);
                inputStream = url.openStream();

                // Read the input stream
                bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

                // Convert the input stream into a bitmap
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

                //Close the streams
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                if (bufferedInputStream != null) {
                    bufferedInputStream.close();
                }

                return new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

And below is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading">

    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.ACTION.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Threading">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".NoThreading">

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And Below is my **layout_for_threading.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/threadingImageView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ImageViewContentDescriptior"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/threadingImageViewButton"
        android:text="@string/ImageViewButton"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/threadingToastButton"
        android:text="@string/ToastButton"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the **Runtime Exception**

```
08-19 00:00:42.134  14371-14563/android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading, PID: 14371
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
            at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
            at android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading.Threading$DownloadImage.downloadImage(Threading.java:92)
            at android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading.Threading$DownloadImage.doInBackground(Threading.java:73)
            at android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading.Threading$DownloadImage.doInBackground(Threading.java:69)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
            at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
            at android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading.Threading$DownloadImage.downloadImage(Threading.java:92)
            at android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading.Threading$DownloadImage.doInBackground(Threading.java:73)
            at android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading.Threading$DownloadImage.doInBackground(Threading.java:69)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
            at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
            at android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading.Threading$DownloadImage.downloadImage(Threading.java:92)
            at android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading.Threading$DownloadImage.doInBackground(Threading.java:73)
            at android.dreamtechprojects.threadingnothreading.Threading$DownloadImage.doInBackground(Threading.java:69)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 6):

Replace `ANDROID.PERMISSION` with `android.permission` in all your `<uses-permission>` elements. Only the last segment (e.g., `INTERNET`) is in all caps.

Most likely, your `<uses-permission>` elements were mis-capitalized due to [this Android Studio bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=157123), which should be fixed in Android Studio 1.4, when that ships (presently only in the canary channel).

Comment: GGWP.
I just changed the cases to lower and it worked!! Thanks a lot :)